# I want to change this sql query into laravel how can i

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

can someone change this query in `laravel`

```
SELECT chat_id
FROM chat_user
GROUP BY chat_id
HAVING MIN(user_id) = <user_id_1> AND MAX(user_id) = <user_id_2>;
```

Comment: show your code what you tried

Comment: i write this
`ChatUser::select('chat_id')
                        ->groupBy('chat_id')

Comment: <user_id> is column or input variable.

Comment: <user_id> is input

Comment: how i can use having min and max in laravel ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries keywords: havingRaw();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query builder or Eloquent way. DB::table or ChatUser::

```
$data = DB::table('chat_user')
    ->select('chat_id')
    ->groupBy('chat_id')
    ->havingRaw('MIN(user_id) = '.$user_id1.' AND MAX(user_id) = '.$user_id2.'')
    ->get();
```

Comment: i not want to use Raw

Comment: That's how it works either you DB::raw in select or havingRaw. it works on laravel Query builder and eloquent. That's what i've learn and read from documentation so far :O

Comment: and its not wokring also

Comment: Please provide the error so i can adjust the query.

Comment: Updated.Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

Lim Kean Phang Has answered in the answer 
Thank you Lim Kean Phang!